# mysqlimport issues "set @@character_set_database=binary" which prevents loading json values

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, mysqlimport, mysql-json

I have been using mysqlimport without problems for a long time, now as mysql 5.7 added json data type support, I'm trying to use mysqlimport with rows containing json data.

Here is an example of a row in csv file that will be imported using mysqlimport:

```
column_A_value,column_B_value,[{"x":20,"y":"some name"}]
```

Notice that the last column type is json. Now when using mysqlimport as the following:

```
mysqlimport -u user -ppass -h localhost --columns='col_A,col_B,col_C' --local --fields-terminated-by=',' some_db /path/to/products.txt
```

I got the following error: `Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'., when using table: products`

However using the generated `LOAD DATA IN FILE` instead of mysqlimport worked without problems! I opened mysql log and checked the generated LOAD DATA IN FILE command when running mysqlimport, then copied and pasted it, and it worked without problems! I ran something like:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/products.txt'
INTO TABLE products
```

And it worked! The only difference is that in the log, when running mysqlimport this line was generated also

```
Query   /*!40101 set @@character_set_database=binary */
```

Then LOAD DATA IN FILE command was generated, so that line is the source of the problem.

So anyway I tried setting character set to utf8,

```
mysqlimport -u user -ppass -h localhost --columns='col_A,col_B,col_C' --local --fields-terminated-by=',' --default-character-set=utf8 some_db /path/to/products.txt
```

but in vain, same error happened.

So any clue how to solve this character set issue please ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your character set configuration:

> show variables like ‘%char%';

Not responding to `--default-character-set` might still be a bug of mysqlimport:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=29712

**Possible Solutions:**

1. Try `SET NAMES utf8;` before the import
2. Try using `mysql` with `--default-character-set=utf8` instead of `mysqlimport`
3. Alter your `my.cnf`:

> ```
> [mysqld]
> init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
> character-set-server=utf8
> collation-server=utf8_general_ci
> default-character-set=utf8
>
> [client]
> default-character-set=utf8
> ```

Comment: None of the above suggestions worked for me. Please note on MYSQL versions 5 or greater you will need to use different values to set the default charset as they deprecated that. Examples here: http://outofcontrol.ca/blog/comments/change-mysql-5.5-default-character-set-to-utf8

Comment: Using `mysql`should be working. As for `my.cnf` it seems that `init-connect` and `default-character-set` no longer belong in the `[mysqld]` section.

Answer (score 0):

Backup mysqlimport to another directory

Change charset using brutal force!!!

```
sed -i 's/character_set_database=binary\ \*/character_set_database=utf8mb4\*/' mysqlimport
```