# Mysql Json : Json Column Update error

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-json

Recently Migrated Table Column from data type Text to Json.

Suppose I have listing table with this table definition and inserted few records in it

```
CREATE TABLE `listing` ( 
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`data` json NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```

when i try to update any data in JSON specified column it throws exception : **data truncation: cannot create a JSON value from a string with Character Set 'binary'**

Though followed article : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

which is also refering to **utf8mb4_bin** because  comparison of JSON values is case-sensitive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL 5.7.12 import cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078119/mysql-5-7-12-import-cannot-create-a-json-value-from-a-string-with-character-set)

Comment: Not a duplicate one because CHARSET is already on utf8mb4

Comment: try without COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin

Comment: please show what data you are storing (example)

Comment: Please, show your insert statement.