# Mysql 5.7.20: Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-5.7

I am facing this issue when importing an SQL file with a table with JSON column.

The database has

Encoding: `utf8mb4`

Collation: `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Here's the table with the json column:

```
CREATE TABLE `tracking_data` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `route` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `data` json NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I have read answers from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078119/mysql-5-7-12-import-cannot-create-a-json-value-from-a-string-with-character-set) on stack overflow which suggest the table must be on `utf8mb4`. Mine's already, but I am facing this issue still.

This is error is still thrown:

> Line XXX: Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET
>   'binary'.

When I run `show session variables like 'char%';`:

```
    Variable_name   Value 

character_set_client    utf8mb4 

character_set_connection    utf8mb4 

character_set_database  utf8mb4 

character_set_filesystem    binary 

character_set_results   utf8mb4 

character_set_server    latin1 

character_set_system    utf8 

character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

How can I fix this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I can reproduce your error if my session character set is `binary`:

```
mysql [localhost] {msandbox} (test) > set names binary;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql [localhost] {msandbox} (test) > insert into tracking_data (route, data, user_id) values ('route', '{"route": "value"}', 1);
ERROR 3144 (22032): Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'.
```

Then I can fix it by setting the session character set to match the table:

```
mysql [localhost] {msandbox} (test) > set names utf8mb4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql [localhost] {msandbox} (test) > insert into tracking_data (route, data, user_id) values ('route', '{"route": "value"}', 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

So I conclude that you have set the session character set to `binary`.

Run `show session variables like 'char%';` and see what it tells you.

Comment: Hi @Bill Karwin

When I run `show session variables like 'char%';`, here's the response:

Comment: ```
Variable_name Value
character_set_client utf8mb4
character_set_connection utf8mb4
character_set_database utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem binary
character_set_results utf8mb4
character_set_server latin1
character_set_system utf8
character_sets_dir /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

Comment: I still am running into this issue when I try and import from a  file.

Comment: Some of those session variables may be different in the session you tried to do the import in.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Run `set names utf8mb4;` in your session before you try the `INSERT`.