# MySQL error when inserting data into JSON column ER_INVALID_JSON_CHARSET

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, sequelize.js

Last Saturday I've upgraded our database into MySQL 8 since AWS is deprecating 5.7.
Everything seemed to be working at first, but now we are seeing issues in our system.

I'm using expressJS & sequelize with Node.js. The frontend is sending the data as a POST, and then we are using a `.create` on that table that has the column as JSON.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
  original: Error: Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'.
      at Packet.asError (/Users/test/code/root/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
      at Execute.execute (/Users/test/code/root/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (/Users/test/code/root/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:481:34)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (/Users/test/code/root/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:97:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (/Users/test/code/root/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/test/code/root/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:104:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
      at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:368:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:341:9)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:278:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
    code: 'ER_INVALID_JSON_CHARSET',
    errno: 3144,
    sqlState: '22032',
    sqlMessage: "Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'.",
    sql: 'INSERT INTO `guest_item` (`id`,`parentId`,`parentBookItemId`,`order`,`itemType`,`itemId`,`itemData`,`createdBy`,`updatedBy`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);',
    parameters: [
      2002,
      null,
      0,
      'contact',
      '5',
      '{"id":1,"name":"JANE DOE","email":"email@example.com","jobTitle":"Director of Sales","primaryPhoneNumber":"1112223333","image":null,"propertyName":""}',
      3,
      3,
      '2024-02-28 10:11:02',
      '2024-02-28 10:11:02'
    ]
  }
```

The table and code are very simple:

```
      itemData: {
        type: DataTypes.JSON,
        allowNull: true
      },
```

```
          await GuestItem.create({
            ...
            itemData: chapterItem.itemData, //this is an object
            ...
          });
```

If I save this data into the database using a SQL query it works, but through Sequelize it doesn't.
Here are the things I have tried:

- Setting a connection charset
- Make sure the POST call is using Content-type application/json with utf8
- Using JSON.stringify and parse to clean up the JSON
- Removing non-utf8 characters using a script.

None of the above has worked. The only solution I found that works is to replace the column with a TEXT and then use getting and setters. We are not using JSON function. But I'm worried there could be issues in our codebase, that could cause issues elsewhere (we have other JSON columns on other tables where we do use JSON functions).

Would someone know what is causing this please?

Comment: You see an error message which is produced by MySQL (error 3144). Check `show variables like 'char%';`, especially client and connection settings, and `show create table guest_item;` for table/column character set.

Comment: show variables, everything is `utf8mb4` except for binary (which seems correct). For the table I have DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Comment: I found a few cases of this error reported in bugs.mysql.com. Most of them claim to be fixed in later releases of MySQL 8.0. What does `SELECT VERSION();` return on your AWS instance?

Comment: I answered a question about this error here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48533341/20860 You said you set the connection charset. Could it be your application set it differently? Can you confirm by querying the connection charset in your application code just before you try the INSERT?

Comment: The MySQL version was the latest one available on AWS:
8.0.36
I've tested your idea Bill, the connection charset is identical right before the query, which is utf8mb4

Comment: *except for binary (which seems correct)* Do you mean filesystem charset? *show variables, everything is utf8mb4* Have you executed this query by the same way? from your program code..

Comment: filesystem is binary yes. I have executed it this way:

const result = await sequelize.query(`show session variables like 'char%';`);
console.log(result);

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question, but it may solve your problem.

With version 8 of MySQL a lot changed, for better or worse is another discussion, but it comes down to compatibility and the direction they have taken is less than ideal.

In steps MariaDB to save the day!

Install the latest stable, set your default charset to utf8mb4, unless you have reasons to not, and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the item that you are encoding, I would have to suggest that the binary object that you are trying to store, albeit an empty one, could well be the image element of itemData (NULL in the example above). I would first encode the "image" into base 64 which is text safe and then retry. it isn't that you have a whole field which is binary, but an element which is and cannot be coerced.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the binary logging format? The binary format for log_bin_use_v1_row_events might be set to true by default in AWS RDS for backward compatibility with MySQL 5.7, even when upgrading to MySQL 8.0. This may potentially cause issues with how JSON data is handled.Try to inspect and change this setting if it’s enabled.

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin_use_v1_row_events';`

If it's ON, you can try turning it off by running:

`SET GLOBAL log_bin_use_v1_row_events = OFF;`