# insert Map<String, Object> into MySQL JSON column

Tags: mysql, json, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I have the following code:

```
public void createFilter(String value1, String value2, Map<String, Object> value3) {        
   jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO mytable(string_column1, string_column2, json_column3) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", new PreparedStatementSetter() {              
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement stmt) throws SQLException {
                stmt.setString(1, value1);
                stmt.setString(2, value2);
                stmt.setObject(3, value3);
            }
        }); 
}
```

The json_column3 is of type JSON.
When I execute this method, I have the following error message:

> Data truncation: Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'.; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'."

I will be very appreciated for any help.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078119/mysql-5-7-12-import-cannot-create-a-json-value-from-a-string-with-character-set

Comment: Duplicate of [38078119](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078119/mysql-5-7-12-import-cannot-create-a-json-value-from-a-string-with-character-set)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL 5.7.12 import cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078119/mysql-5-7-12-import-cannot-create-a-json-value-from-a-string-with-character-set)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It is similar but not the same as the question in the aforementioned comments. I believe the above 3 comments are wrong.

Comment: I tried various of changes on charset (utf8mb4), but it doesn't fixed in this case.

Comment: This works: String jsonStr = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(value3); stmt.setString(3, jsonStr);

Comment: This should be the answer.